# Updating A Table Based On The Count() From Its Many-to-Many Table

Tags: mysql

I have a table of groups, of people, and a many-to-many table of `group_id`, `person_id` pairs.  `group` has a count column which should store the current number of people in each group.  I'd like to update this information in one SQL command if I can.  I imagine some kind of subquery would let me accomplish this, but I'm not sure how.

This query successfully gives me a mapping of group_ids to their count

```
SELECT `group_id`, COUNT(`group_id`) FROM `group-person` GROUP BY `group_id`;
```

This query fails, but if it worked, this would be what I'm trying to do

```
UPDATE `group`,`group-person` WHERE `group`.`id` = `group-person`.`group_id`
SET `group`.`count` = COUNT(`group-person`.`group_id`)
GROUP BY `group-person`.`group_id`;
```

Comment: you cant do GROUP BY in update query ,

Comment: Yeah, I know, the query fails, it was just how I imagined it could possibly work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `group`
SET `group`.`count` = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   `group_person`
    WHERE  `group_person`.`group_id` = `group`.`id`
)
```

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed, that was lightning fast.

Comment: I'm afraid that's what hapens when you remember the 'SQL-86' Standard.